# Passing variables from one controller to another with $rootscope

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to pass the id from one controller onto the next using $rootscope. I thought it was as simple as setting the variable to $rootscope, but for some reason when i check in console it comes up as undefined.  This variable will not change and i'd like to have it be "global" for all following controllers.  Any reason why this isn't getting set?

```
  .controller('CubeHeadCtrl', ['$scope',  '$rootScope', '$stateParams', 'cubeHeadFactory', 'localUserFactory', '$q',  function($scope, $rootScope, $stateParams, cubeHeadFactory, localUserFactory, $q) {

    cubeHeadFactory.get({ urlName: $stateParams.urlName }, function(data){
      $scope.cube = data;
      $rootScope.home_channel_id = $scope.cube.home_channel_id;
    });
  }])


  .controller('CubeLiveCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$stateParams', 'cubeHeadFactory', 'cubeLiveFactory',  function($scope, $rootScope, $stateParams, cubeHeadFactory, cubeLiveFactory) {
    $scope.homeid = $rootScope.home_channel_id;

        cubeLiveFactory.query({dynamicChannelID: $scope.homeid}, function(data){
           $scope.cubeLive = data;
           console.log('This is there we check out the ID with = ' +$scope.homeid+ ' isnt that nice');
    });
  }])
```

Comment: Prefer a service for sharing data between controllers as mentioned by @mpm. However, I'm guessing your actual problem of not seeing variable changes propagate is due to assignment of primitives (i.e. instead of `$scope.cube.home_channel_id` try `$scope.cube` and refactor appropriately).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dont use $rootScope unless you have a pretty good reason to do so.in your case there is none. Use services instead

```
.factory('MyService',function(){
    return { myVar1:""};
})
.controller('Ctrl1',function($scope,MyService){
    $scope.MyService=MyService;
    MyService.myVar1="foo"
})
.controller('Ctrl2',function($scope,MyService){
    $scope.MyService=MyService;
});
```

Comment: I've heard this before and I'm still a bit fuzzy on it.  Is there a reason why its so bad to use rootscope?  Will it create performance issues?

Comment: It will not create any performance issues, but it is as bad a thing as is polluting the global namespace. Anything set in the rootScope should be used sparingly. You should provide a plunker, because what you intend to do should work in any browser. See this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/qttTaF9fpdTu7vOTnY0N?p=preview