# Passing value from one page to another when routing

Tags: angularjs

I have a page in which there is a drop down, My goal is when I select any value from drop down and click on Next,It is switching to Next page using ngRouteProvider and doing $http.post , I need to pass data as payback load.

```
                  .when('/xyz/step2', {
                    templateUrl: partial('replacStep2.html'),
                    controller: 'xyzCtrl',
                    resolve: {
                        cardTypeDetails: ['$http', function ($http) {
                            return       $http.post(appContext('xyz.json'),{});

                        }]
                    }

                })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a factory and set a variable inside it, later you can inject that factory inside your resolve block and access your variable through it.

```
resolve: {
    cardTypeDetails: ['$http','sharedFactory', function ($http,sharedFactory) {
    console.log(sharedFactory.sharedVariable); //use it like this 
    return $http.post(appContext('xyz.json'),{});

    }]
}
```

and factory

```
angular.module('demoApp').factory('sharedFactory',function(){
    return {
        sharedVariable:null
    };
});
```

Or in same way you can use `$rootScope` to pass variables (but not great for performance if you do for large no. of variables)

[Passing variables from one controller to another with $rootscope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23123757/passing-variables-from-one-controller-to-another-with-rootscope)

Comment: How to inject factory in resolve block or any example of injecting $rootscope will also help.

Comment: just like you injected `$http` service. I update my answer accordingly.

Comment: how can I pass data when doing JSON call. When ever I am trying to passed data it is showing , Unauthorized error.                                           return $http.post(appContext('xyz.json'),{name:'Ankit'});

Comment: That is mapper issue from Java side. Thanks